# Comunicar ASP.NET com Windows Forms

Tags: asp.net, winforms, socket

O problema é o seguinte, trabalho com SAT-CFe e a comunicação com este é feito via USB o que impossibilita meu sistema web de fazer a comunicação direta com ele.

O que eu fiz, criei uma aplicação desktop que faz essa comunicação com o Hardware SAT e se comunica com o sistema ASP.NET, fiz isso usando Socket.  Funciona. Porém tem uma problema quando o XML que eu envio via socket é maior do que 6kb ele chega incompleto e não vai de jeito nenhum.

Já aumentei *buffer*, fiz de tudo e não cheguei a lugar algum. Vou postar os metodos cliente e servidor:

Cliente:

```
   //Mensagem de Retorno Servidor em Byte
       byte[] retornoServidorByte = new byte[1024 * 5000];
       // byte[] retornoServidorByte = new byte[10485760];
        //Tenta enviar o arquivo ao cliente
        try
        {
            //Cria o IpEnd que sera o destino .. Este é atribuido o valor real abaixo
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);


                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(Auxiliares.sipRealCliente);
                ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, 5859);

            //Cria o Socket
            Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

            //Convert em Bit o xml a ser enviado ao cliente
            byte[] clientData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            try
            {
                //Coneta com o Cliente
                clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
                //Envia os dados
                clientSock.Send(clientData);
                //Recebe o retorno do Servidor
                clientSock.Receive(retornoServidorByte);
            }
            catch (SocketException soc)
            {
                return soc.Message;
            }



            clientSock.Close();//Fecha a conexao com o Cliente

            //Monta o retorno em String
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(retornoServidorByte);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
```

Servidor:

```
 try
        {
            //Classes
            Sat sat = new Sat();
            Config config = new Config();


            WriteLog("Iniciando servidor...");

            //Cria o Ip que subira o servidor
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.None, 0000);
            //Verifica se usara ipLocal automatico ou o Ip configurado
            if (config.ConfigAutomatica == true)
            {
                ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Config.GetIp()), 5859);
            }
            else
            {
                ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(config.Ip), config.Porta);
            }

            //Cria o SOCK
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

            //Especifica ao Sock qual Ip Sera usadao
            sock.Bind(ipEnd);

            //Começa Ouvir no maximo 100 Solicitaçoes
            sock.Listen(100);

            WriteLog("Servidor iniciado e escutando em: " + ipEnd.Address + ":" + ipEnd.Port);
            WriteLog("Aguardando nova conexao cliente...");

            Thread listen = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {

                    //Aceita a conexao
                    using (Socket clientSock = sock.Accept())
                    {

                        WriteLog("Cliente: " + clientSock.RemoteEndPoint + " Conectado");

                        //Cria uma Thread
                        //var threadData = new Thread(() =>
                        //{
                        //Armazena o retorno vindo do cliente
                       byte[] clientData = new byte[1024*5000];
                     //   byte[] clientData = new byte[10485760];
                        //Recebe os arquivos do Cliente
                      int k = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

                        WriteLog("Recebendo dados cliente...");


                        //Converte o valor vindo do servidor para string
                        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clientData).Replace("\0", string.Empty);

                        //Troca a codificação do XML para UTF-8
                        xml = xml.Replace("utf-16", "utf-8");

                        WriteLog("Arquivo Recebido com sucesso!!");
                        var retorno = "Recebido com Sucesso!";

                        //Pega o retorno do SAT e envia devolta ao cliente
                        byte[] arquivoRetorno = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(retorno);
                        clientSock.Send(arquivoRetorno);

                        //Fecha a conexao
                        clientSock.Close();

                        WriteLog(System.Environment.NewLine);
                        WriteLog("Aguardando nova conexao cliente...");
                        //});
                        //threadData.Start(); //Inicia novamente a Thread
                    }
                }
            });
            listen.IsBackground = true;
            listen.Name = "Servidor";
            listen.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Config.GravarLog(Types.TipoLog.Erro, ex, "");
            WriteLog("Ocorreu uma falha: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Gostaria de saber o que posso mexer no código para arrumar isto, ou se existe alguma outra forma melhor de se fazer essa comunicação entre uma Aplicação Web com uma Aplicação Local Desktop.
Fico agradecido pela ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket não é a melhor maneira para fazer essa comunicação entre sistemas enviando arquivos. Para mensagens curtas ponta-ponta, é válido. O melhor no caso, é você trabalhar com um serviço WCF que irá realizar esta tarefa legal.

Nos dois links abaixo, você pode fazer um pequeno download de um demo que pode te ajudar nisto:

1. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Boa sorte!

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Belos exemplos vou estudar a implementação deles no meu projeto..